# How to get the count of rows in a table through the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to get the count of rows in my table that meet the requirements.

```
#<Ahoy::Event:123abc
  id: "123abc",
  visit_id: "123abc",
  user_id: 1,
  name: "post_succeeded",
  properties:
   {"info"=>nil,
    "type"=>"post-to-host",
    "value"=>0.1,
    "partner"=>"Glassdoor",
    "request"=>
     {"url"=>"http://glassdoor.com",
      "params"=>
       {"v"=>"1",
        "t.k"=>"bac",
        "t.p"=>"92",
        "action"=>"doJobAlert",
        "format"=>"json",
        "userip"=>"::1",
        "useragent"=>"",
        "utm_medium"=>"cpc",
        "utm_source"=>"SimplyJobs",
        "emailAddress"=>"gscott@whereswaldo.com",
        "utm_campaign"=>"simplyjobs.com",
        "rawLocationName"=>"12345"}},
        "success"=>true},
    time: Sat, 07 May 2016 19:46:19 UTC +00:00>
```

Requirements: 'type' => 'post-to-host' AND 'partner' => 'Glassdoor' AND 'success' => true AND 'time' => Time.now.month/day/year

This was my attempt:

```
Ahoy::Event.where("properties ->> 'type' = ?", 'post-to-host' AND "properties ->> 'partner' = ?", 'Glassdoor' AND "properties ->> 'request' ->> 'success' = ?", true AND time: Time.now.month AND time: Time.now.day AND time: Time.now.year).count
```

I am not so familiar with SQL, any help is appreciated.

Comment: This does not look like SQL - is it anything to do with Ruby on  Rails?

Comment: Yes, I was viewing documentation here: 

https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#querying-properties

Comment: by tables you mean tables, or all rows in that table that meet your requirements?

Comment: All rows in that table which meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on using [where](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) clause in rails
The answer will something along these lines

```
Ahoy::Event.where("properties ->> 'type' = ? AND 
properties ->> 'partner' = ? AND properties ->> 
'request' ->> 'success' = ? AND time = ?",  'post-to-host', 'Glassdoor', true , Time.now).count
```

Comment: Remove the `"` from the 1st and 2nd `?` in your example according to the docs. The query for 'success' gives an error. Removing it gave me a count, so you're on the right track.

Comment: As stated in the previous comment, the query for 'success' is incorrect. Further testing shows the 'time' query is also incorrect as well. Although this was a step in the right direction, it is not the correct answer.